# Wireshark - Bluetooth LE decoding a HCI Log

Tags: wireshark

I have a bluetooth LE home automation style device, that connects to a mobile app. There are 2 values which are updated roughly every second. I'm trying to extract these numbers from the payload. I've narrowed the frames down to these examples below.

```
00-02-7B-02-9E-00-0F-3B-84-DD-30
00-02-7C-02-A8-00-0F-3B-84-DD-30
00-02-7C-02-A9-00-0F-3B-84-DD-30
00-02-7B-02-A2-00-0F-3B-85-60-42
00-02-7C-02-AD-00-0F-3B-85-1E-B9
```

The 2 numbers I'm trying to extract should be a PSI/bar/other pressure value of around 50psi/339bar and the other should be between 1 and 5ish.

It looks like the values are split on the `00` in the hex.

I've been using this tool [hex to int converter](http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) to try and split the hex up, but I can't get the values I'm expecting.